# node.js not working Object.keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

```
var list = {"you": 100, "me": 75, "foo": 116, "bar": 15};
keysSorted = Object.keys(list).sort(function(a,b){return list[a]-list[b]})
alert(keysSorted);     // bar,me,you,foo
```

from [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

I'm doing Object sorting. Above source working in Javascript.
But not working in Node.js. I have an error like this.

```
keysSorted = Object.keys(list).sort(function(a,b){return list[a]-list[b]})
                    ^
TypeError: Object.keys is not a function
```

I don't know why. Please help me.

Comment: What does `node -v` show?

Comment: what is node version  v 6.7 it's working fine

Comment: Are you redeclaring `Object` somewhere? like `var Object = 'something else';`? Not sure how Node would react to that but seeing `TypeError: Object.keys is not a function` leaves me just that option...

Comment: Tested in node `6.2.2` and you can actually do `var Object = 'something else';` and erase the Object native value.... can that be your problem? Check your variables...

Comment: OMG!!!!!!! I found my mistake. I declared `var Object = 'requrie file';`. Thank u so much guys. You're genius.

Comment: Why did this get a downvote?

Comment: @EricMajerus Maybe It's my mistake.. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you are using an out-dated Node.js version, v0.10 or v0.12. To check the version try running `node -v`.

This old version doesn't support `Object.keys`. You can check supported features for every Node.js versions [here](http://node.green).

My advice is to update to Node.js version to 6.9.1. This version is current LTS (Long-term support).

Comment: Object.keys() on objects works just fine with node v0.10.

Comment: As you say, I update node.js to `6.9.1`. But still not workingTT. appearing same error .

Comment: I solve it. I declared `var Object;` Anyway thank you answering! :)

Comment: This is incorrect. `Object.fit()` [works fine on Node 0.10](https://runkit.com/bfred-it/object-keys-on-node-0-10)